# SceneKit Style Transfer with coreML

Tags: scenekit, coreml

Goal:
SceneKit Style Transfer with coreML

How:
Grabbing CVPixelBuffer from a SceneKit frame, like on WWDC video bellow:
[image]
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10642/

Tried:
I tried accessing a SCN frame, but it doesn't seem to have access to CVPixelBuffer

Question:
How can I grab CVPixelBuffer from a SceneKit frame? Or is there a better way to do Style Transfer in SceneKit?

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a description like this.

Here I stylize offline the virtual object texture with a different style but I want to do even more.

I think it displays the virtual object texture through matel. I try to get the CVPixelBuffer through CIImage, and process it through arView.renderCallbacks.postProcess to get real-time processing effects, which is much more convenient than getting video processing, but how to process data through matel I am not sure, hope someone can provide more information.

You can refer to this speech video
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10075/